# How to get JSON from a WCF Data Services, DataServiceQuery call in Silverlight?

Tags: json, silverlight, wcf-data-services

**Background:** I have a WCF Data Service with a Silverlight application that is currently using atom pub xml. I want to use JSON to lessen the size of the payload.
I read that you can JSON from the service webget using the following code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
```

Can I modify the header for a DataServiceQuery call or a localContext.BeginExecute (for WebGets)?

```
// WCF Data Services Query Proxy
DataServiceQuery<T> query = filterExpression as DataServiceQuery<T>;

// Execute the ASYNC query against the model
query.BeginExecute(new AsyncCallback((iar) =>
{ ...});
```

or

```
// Create new context with the WCF service to force only save this entity
VisiconnEDM localContext = new VisiconnEDM(new Uri(entityServiceURL, UriKind.Absolute));

// execute the query asynchronously 
localContext.BeginExecute<T>(urlQuery,(IAsyncResult iar) =>{ ...},null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you would modify the header for DataServiceRequest the client library of WCF DS doesn't have support for reading JSON responses, so it would not be able to read the response. The currently suggested approach to decrease the payload size is to use GZip.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction (again). I appreciate your answering my questions in the pas as well. I looked for information about using GZip, but didn't find a good link. Do you have a recommendation? (we don't have IIS 7 for our servers yet)

Comment: GZip is pretty much web server specific, so your bets bet will be to ask a separate question on that regard. I know very little about that unfortunately.